# Incremental billing with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I'm looking for a recommendation of a payment method for woocommerce that will allow for the following:

Let's say the client wants to spend 10 000 schmeckles, but we don't charge the full 10 000 schmeckles. We want to bill the client as he/she uses the money. So they will commit to 10 000, but at every 250 schmeckles worth of services used we want to bill 250.. until the 10 000 runs out.

I'm not sure what this is called and I tried googling it, but no luck.

Does anyone have any recommendations that I can use as a starting point please? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the case of single authorize (10000) and multiple captures (250-each)?

Comment: @jagdeep yes, or it could be as simple as a commitment of 10 000 and then 250 per run

Comment: This may be of some interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312774/multiple-captures-on-a-single-credit-card-authorization